# How to enable MFA on PowerApp?

Tags: powerapp, multifactor-authentication

I have built some simple PowerApps (not portal) and works fine on Android and iPhone. But I am not sure how to enable MFA on PowerApp. Is there any official document available? I can only find discussion for this topic on other forum. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is and it's quite simple actually.

You can configure Conditional Access with MFA to the specific application for the specific set of users as per your requirement. Read on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-tutorial-require-mfa#create-a-conditional-access-policy-that-requires-mfa.

Follow the guide, and then on the Cloud Apps, select **Microsoft PowerApps**. Ensure you've logged out and cleared all browser caches before you test it.

If you are wondering: how to configure MFA on a specific app? Unfortunately no, it will apply to all once it's turned on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a test account (domain is onmicrosoft.com). When I login azrue portal, click on the Azure Active Directory page, there is NO "Security" section. Do you know what is missing?

Comment: Are you sure your account has global admin access in Azure? It's a little bit down there you need to scroll.

Comment: I clicked on Azure Ad,  in the middle it told me I am login as global admin.

Comment: Hi it seems they change UI again. I clicked on "security" under "Manage" section and I am able to set conditional access with MFA. In "user and group" I have specific included my account. Then in my Android phone, I sign off my PowerApp and sign in again. I can signin with one-factor (login+password). Did I missed anything?

Comment: Thanks Radityo, it works now. It is just a matter of time. Last question, is there any charge for the Azure authentication service? Thank you.

Comment: Glad to see that worked for you! Azure AD itself is free, it seems also free with Conditional Access too. But you'll need to pay once it touches other services like Office 365, etc.

Comment: Conditional Access requires an Azure AD P1 license, it’s not free.  MFA can be free in certain circumstances (protecting GAs or everyone (if security defaults is enabled)).

Comment: Ooops..., my apologies. Maybe I have given partial correct information. Conditional Access as a whole is not free, but the basic MFA is free. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing#feature-comparison-of-versions

Comment: @RadityoArdi I have consulted a MS support about cost issue and she said it is free. I doubt, too. However, I do enable MFA without any payment so far. Maybe because I am the global admin